# how to get the input value of dynamically generated textboxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button to add textarea, but how to retrieve values from the text areas.
I have tried using

```
document.getElementById('newutterances').value;
```

but its not working.

Please help, as I am new to JavaScript.

```html
<html>
    <body>
    <div id="newutterance"></div>
    <input type="button" value="Add Text Area" onClick="addTextArea();">
    <button type="button" onClick="getValue()">Get Value</button>
    
     <script type="text/javascript">
       function addTextArea() 
       {
       var intTextBox = 0;
       intTextBox++;
       var objNewDiv = document.createElement('div');
       objNewDiv.setAttribute('id', 'div_' + intTextBox);
       objNewDiv.innerHTML = 'Textbox ' + intTextBox + ': <input type="text" id="tb_' + intTextBox + '" name="tb_"/>';
       document.getElementById('newutterance').appendChild(objNewDiv);
         
       }
        </script>
         <script type="text/javascript">
       function getValue() 
       {
       var value = document.getElementById('newutterance');
          return value;
       }
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: IDs must be unique. You can keep a reference to the divs you create though. Just put them in an array.

Comment: Your `intTextBox` var needs to be global otherwise it will just be 1 each time (you reset it to 0 every time you call the function).  Also what value do you want?  You add multiple textboxes so are you wanting each value or the sum of all values?  `newutterances` doesn't have a `.value` as it is a div

Comment: I want to retrieve each of the values,  added through textareas, to store in localstorage. @Pete

Comment: Where are you outputting these values?

Comment: Suppose, I store the values in a variable called 'value', and then I store in the localStorage like- localStorage.setItem("key_values", JSON.stringify(value));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add some class for fields and use `document.getElementsByClass()`;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var count = 0;
    function addTextArea() {
        count++;
        var objNewDiv = document.createElement('div');
        objNewDiv.innerHTML = 'Textbox ' + count + ': <input type="text" class="field" name="tb_"/>';
        document.getElementById('newutterance').appendChild(objNewDiv);
    }
    function getValue() {
        var fields = document.getElementsByClassName('field');
        var values = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
            values.push(fields[i].value);
        }
        return values;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Nick. :) :)

Answer (score 0):

With this code snippet below, I get the value of your input field, which you've created, and print it using console.log().

```
var button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
     var input = document.querySelector('#newutterance input[type="text"]');
     var inputValue = input.value; 
     console.log(inputValue);
});
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="newutterance"></div>
  <input type="button" value="Add Text Area" onClick="addTextArea();">
  <button type="button">Get Value</button>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function addTextArea() {
      var intTextBox = 0;
      intTextBox++;
      var objNewDiv = document.createElement('div');
      objNewDiv.setAttribute('id', 'div_' + intTextBox);
      objNewDiv.innerHTML = 'Textbox ' + intTextBox + ': <input type="text" id="tb_' + intTextBox + '" name="tb_"/>';
      document.getElementById('newutterance').appendChild(objNewDiv);

    }
    var button = document.querySelector('button');

    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
      var input = document.querySelector('#newutterance input[type="text"]');
      var inputValue = input.value;
      console.log(inputValue);
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```